# Why we add P rather than simply changing M in the design of Go scheduler?

Tags: go, scheduler, software-design

As we know, from Go 1.0 to Go 1.1, the most important improvement of Go's scheduler is adding P to GM to make GPM. We can see the original design doc there [Scalable Go Scheduler Design Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TTj4T2JO42uD5ID9e89oa0sLKhJYD0Y_kqxDv3I3XMw/edit#heading=h.qjzelsx7rj5j)

I am confused why we add P to store the local runq and mcache rather than simply putting these things to M. As the saying goes,"If Not Necessary, the Substantiality will not be Added".
It's obvious that the former adds an entity while the latter don't.

Why we choose the former?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure "If Not Necessary, the Substantiality will not be Added" is not a saying; however I take it to be a variant of Occam's Razor: don't unnecessarily multiply entities. Yet 'P's (processors) are not superfluous notions when it comes to the scheduling of processes - if you lack any concept corresponding to the underlying hardware that runs processes (other than the max number of processors and the number free), then your scheduling is actually too abstract. I am not an expert on the Go scheduler, and there are several problematic elements identified in the linked paper with it, but the core of the improvement seems to relate to the implementation of "work stealing", whereby idle Ps try to steal waiting Gs from other Ps. This is efficient because the P knows when it becomes idle, whereas an M on its own has no idea about idle hardware.

Comment: I expect it's a saying in a non-English language, which has been translated.

Comment: It could also be a saying among close friends, or something. Anything can be a saying, once it's said more than once :)

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, I'm not a native English speaker, it's just a translated saying.

Comment: @see sharper Occam's Razor is exactly what I want to quote.

Comment: @see sharper Can I understand your answer like this: the main reason why it adds P to GM is because it wants to implement "work stealing" which cannot be implemented if there is only M.

Comment: Exactly, although other benefits are mentioned such as memory efficiency. Work stealing has the benefit of efficiently redistributing jobs among available hardware processors, which can’t be achieved if the scheduler has no concept of a P.